# Add column to table

Tags: tables

I have a table that is produced with the code below and would like to extend it, adding another column that will contain names for {"Group1" and "Group2"} such that, to the left of this data, it will say, "Condition1", "Condition2", "Condition3". That is, each Condition with have two rows, one with "Group1" and one with "Group2" data. I am a newborn LaTeX:er and the tables that are produced with LaTeX is supernice. Although, its difficult to get started with it. So, how could I go about to answer this question. Some suggest to have e.g:

```
 \begin{tabular}{rlrrrrr}
 \end{tabular}%

 \begin{tabular}{r} % here is the added column 

 \end{tabular}
```

Although, in the above stuff, its not as complicated as with my table with many different levels.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \usepackage{caption}                      
 \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{changepage} % remove?
 \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\hf}[2]{%HeaderFormat
   \multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}%
 }
 \begin{document}
 \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
 \begin{table*}
 \centering
 \ra{1.3}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
 \setcounter{table}{0} % This makes the caption title 'Table 1:'
 \caption{Mean (sd) before}
 \begin{tabular}{%
   @{}>{}l% Remove space from edge, Set first column in italice
   *{4}{% 4 columns of the following
     r@{\,}% right column for the mean value, and set the space between the two numbers to be exactly `\,`-space
>{(}r<{)}% right column for the standard deviation, add paratheses before and after
}%
   @{}l@{\hspace{2em}}% Need to control the space before and after the column with @{}, so that no `\tabcolsep` is inserted, and then we add the exact space we need.
   *{4}{r@{\,}>{(}r<{)}}% Same as above
   }

 \toprule
 & \hf{8}{Obj1} &&\hf{8}{Obj2}\\

 \cmidrule{2-9} \cmidrule{11-18}
 & \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty} && \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty}\\
 \midrule
 &\hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} &  \hf{2}{CSY} && \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY}\\
 \midrule
 Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
 Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
 Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{adjustwidth}
 \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Does this mean you can't just edit the table to put the new column at the beginning? Is it automatically generated?

Comment: Yes to your first question. And no its not automatically generated :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really get it. If the table is not automatically generated, why can't you just edit it?

Comment: I didnt know how to proceed.

Comment: Ah, so the problem wasn't that editing the code isn't an option, it's just that you didn't know how to do that. See if my answer helps a bit in that respect.

Comment: So you meant you did'nt know how to edit the table? Rather than that it couldn't be edited?

Comment: Exactly. Torbjörn, your solution was exactly what I was looking for. It was simpler than adding a column and I found a difficulty in aligning the new column exactly (it was shifted one pixel up :) However solving that misalignment would also make the perfect solution for this problem, although, again, yours was simpler I think. Much thanx to you.

Comment: @Augusti (While I don't like rep-fishing:) Consider switching accepted answer then, so that others who see this question can more easily identify what you considered the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\cn}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}{#1}}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\midrulecompensation
\setlength\midrulecompensation{\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep+\lightrulewidth}
```

And put this before your tabular (make sure there is no intervening white space):

```
 \begin{tabular}{%
   @{}l % Remove space from edge
   }%
   \toprule
   \\[\midrulecompensation]
   \\
   \midrule
   \\
   \midrule
   \cn{Condition1} \\
   \\[\midrulecompensation]
   \cn{Condition 2} \\
   \\
   \cn{Condition 3} \\
   \\[\midrulecompensation] 
   \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}%
```

The `\midrulecompensation` is to make up for the space that the `\midrule` takes in the other tabular, otherwise they wouldn't line up.

Comment: You are a genius.

Comment: I edited your text because when I incorporated this the new column wasnt alidgned with the rest. I shifted the first midrulecompensation up one step, and added to other. Then it was right.

Comment: Adding additional midrulecompensations is incorrect unless the other table has \midrule's that are not in your original code.
Also my code is not correct: instead of \lightrulewidth it should use \cmidrulewidth (and then the should probably called \cmidrulecompensation.
But editing the original table is obviously better. I thought it was not acceptable to edit the table.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why one would add a separate `tabular` instead of editing the existing one. You need to add a new `l` column at the start, add a `&` at the start of each row, increase the column numbers in the `\cmidrule`s by 1, and add `Condition N` in the appropriate rows.

I also reduced the space in the middle (between the `Obj` "groups"), and added `\small` to reduce the font size, as the table is rather wide.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \usepackage{caption}                      
 \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{changepage} % remove?
 \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\hf}[2]{%HeaderFormat
   \multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}%
 }

 \begin{document}
% \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

 \begin{table*}
 \centering\small % <-- I addded \small
 \ra{1.3}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
 \setcounter{table}{0} % This makes the caption title 'Table 1:'
 \caption{Mean (sd) before}
 \begin{tabular}{%
   @{}l>{}l% Remove space from edge, Set first column in italice
   *{4}{% 4 columns of the following
     r@{\,}% right column for the mean value, and set the space between the two numbers to be exactly `\,`-space
>{(}r<{)}% right column for the standard deviation, add paratheses before and after
}%
   @{}l@{\hspace{1em}}% Need to control the space before and after the column with @{}, so that no `\tabcolsep` is inserted, and then we add the exact space we need.
   *{4}{r@{\,}>{(}r<{)}}% Same as above
   }

 \toprule
 && \hf{8}{Obj1} &&\hf{8}{Obj2}\\

 \cmidrule{3-10} \cmidrule{12-19}
 && \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty} && \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty}\\
 \midrule
 &&\hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} &  \hf{2}{CSY} && \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY}\\
 \midrule
Condition 1 & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
Condition 2 & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
Condition 3 & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{adjustwidth}
 \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```

Or if you want `Condition N` to be in the middle of a two-row cell, add `\usepackage{multirow}`, and use `\multirow{2}{*}{Condition 1}` instead of `Condition 1`.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \usepackage{caption}                      
 \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{changepage} % remove?
 \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\hf}[2]{%HeaderFormat
   \multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}%
 }
 \usepackage{multirow}

 \begin{document}
% \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

 \begin{table*}
 \centering\small % <-- I addded \small
 \ra{1.3}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{}
 \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
 \setcounter{table}{0} % This makes the caption title 'Table 1:'
 \caption{Mean (sd) before}
 \begin{tabular}{%
   @{}l>{}l% Remove space from edge, Set first column in italice
   *{4}{% 4 columns of the following
     r@{\,}% right column for the mean value, and set the space between the two numbers to be exactly `\,`-space
>{(}r<{)}% right column for the standard deviation, add paratheses before and after
}%
   @{}l@{\hspace{1em}}% Need to control the space before and after the column with @{}, so that no `\tabcolsep` is inserted, and then we add the exact space we need.
   *{4}{r@{\,}>{(}r<{)}}% Same as above
   }

 \toprule
 && \hf{8}{Obj1} &&\hf{8}{Obj2}\\

 \cmidrule{3-10} \cmidrule{12-19}
 && \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty} && \hf{4}{Objectx} & \hf{4}{Objecty}\\
 \midrule
 &&\hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} &  \hf{2}{CSY} && \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY} & \hf{2}{CSX} & \hf{2}{CSY}\\
 \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Condition 1} & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Condition 2} & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Condition 3} & Group1 &0.50&0.23 & 0.55&0.25 & 0.34&0.16 & 0.37&0.20 && 0.33&0.18 & 0.38&0.16 & 0.27&0.17 & 0.23&0.17 \\
 & Group2 &0.43&0.17 & 0.44&0.14 & 0.39&0.18 & 0.35&0.15 && 0.32&0.20 & 0.31&0.18 & 0.25&0.19 & 0.26&0.22 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{adjustwidth}
 \end{table*}
 \end{document}
```